# Create folder based on group of files

Tags: batch-file

I have files with varying names...

```
Tim-01.jpg
Tim-02.jpg
Tim-03.jpg
jack-01.jpg
jack-02.jpg
jack-03.jpg etc in a single folder
```

I want to move all tim files into Tim folder and jack files to Jack folder etc.

Can it be done using .bat files ? If yes, please share the code for it.

Thank You.

Comment: Type `copy /?` at the command prompt. It's all there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT - Changed code to reduce the number of file moves. Now, all files with the same prefix get moved in one command.

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions

    rem source of images
    set "_dir=."

    rem for each jpg with a dash in its name
    for %%f in ("%_dir%\*-*.jpg") do (

        rem if the file still exists (maybe it has been moved) 
        rem then split the file name with the dash as delimiter
        if exist "%%~ff" for /F "tokens=1 delims=-" %%s in ("%%~nf") do (

            rem and if we get a folder target, move the all the files 
            rem with same prefix to proper folder
            if not "%%~s"=="" (
                robocopy "%_dir%" "%_dir%\%%~s" "%%~s-*.jpg" /mov /njs /njh
            )
        )
    )

    endlocal
```

EDIT2 - Changed to adapt to comments

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    rem source of images
    set "_dir=."

    rem for each jpg with a dash in its name
    for %%f in ("%_dir%\*-??.jpg") do (

        rem if the file still exists (maybe it has been moved) 
        if exist "%%~ff" (

            rem get the filename without the 3 last characters
            set "_target=%%~nf"
            set "_target=!_target:~0,-3!"

            rem and if we get a folder target, move the all the files 
            rem with same prefix to proper folder
            if not "!_target!"=="" (
                robocopy "%_dir%" "%_dir%\!_target!" "!_target!-??.jpg" /mov /njs /njh
            )
        )
    )

    endlocal
```

Comment: This worked but have few problems. This code removes everything after the first '-'. I want to remove only the last 3 characters (-01, -02, -03). Can you tell me how can it be done. Thank You

Comment: @user3020621: How are the files named ?

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response... The files are named jack-home-01.jpg, jack-home-02.jpg, jack-college-party-01.jpg, jack-college-party-02.jpg etc. I want folders like jack-home, jack-college-party etc.

Comment: @user3020621: Adapted.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal
set sourcedir=c:\sourcedir
for /f "tokens=1*delims=-" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*-*.*") do (
 md "%sourcedir%\%%a" 2>nul
 echo move "%sourcedir\%%a-%%b" "%sourcedir%\%%a\"
)
```

Note that the `2>nul` suppresses error messages created when an attempt is made to recreate an existing directory

The `MOVE` is merely `ECHO`ed. Remove the `ECHO` keyword to activae the `move`. It may also be prudent to append `>nul` to the `MOVE` statement to suppress the "1 file(s) moved" message.

Answer (score 1):

As you may know, there are no arrays in Batch. So let's just use one.

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
for /f "tokens=1*delims=-" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d *-*.jpg') do set "$%%a=%%a"
for /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a in ('set $') do robocopy "%cd%" "%cd%\%%b" "%%b*" /mov /l
```

Remove `/l` from `robocopy` to make it working.